# Looping in Flash

Tags: flash

I'm using FLash MX - 2004 and have a slide-show with 70 frames. When it plays and hits frame-70 I want it to loop and start playing again at frame-35 (and run endlessly). However, the default behavior is that it restarts at frame-1.

How do I configure the show to restart at frame-35 once it plays through?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

On frame 70, in the Actions - Frame, write gotoAndPlay(35). This will cause it to go back to that frame and follow this loop continuously.

Comment: @user Please accept the answer by checking the green check-mark near the answer so that this question will appear as answered in the listings and he'll get 15 points.